# VB.Net DataGridView Dataset changes to sql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is prob basic question. When I create a datagrid I typically use a view and or tables from MS SQL. If I make an update in SQL for the view or alter the changes they do not comeover to my vb.net application. What I currently do is create a new project and copy and paste everything and add a new dataset. Is there a better way.

Comment: Use a WebService to update data through. When WebService gets the call it can use duplex communication to send a message to any program that is connected to it that could set off the code to refresh you DGV.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable in your application and populate it with the table or view (or Select * from table) query results . This DataTable you can assign to your Datagrid view. You can create a timer (tick event) on your application and run the select query to update your applications datagrid every x seconds (or milliseconds). This may be a bit expensive and not pretty UI wise.
A better way would be to make your application sentient enough to recognise that the SQL server table has been updated. If the only way to update the SQL server is through your application , I suggest you can attach an event ( to the update_db or add_to_db code in your application ) and refresh your view whenever that event gets called.